# The Birthday Problem - at least 2 out of N

Tags: java, birthday-paradox

I received a bit of a modified birthday problem-
I need to run a function that returns the probability that at least two out of N persons share the same birthday. Then a
main function that calculates the minimal n such that this probability is at least 0.5.
I tried to write one but the only outputs are 0 or 1, I would appreciate debugging or pointing out what I did wrong.
here is what I've done:

```
public class Birthday {

    public static double probSameBirthday(int n) {
        double days = 1 / 365;   // number of days
        int i, person = 0;       // total number of people
        double noProb = 0;
        int people = n;

        for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            person = i;
            noProb = (1 - ( noProb * (1 - (person - 1) * days))) / 100;
        }

        return (noProb);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(probSameBirthday(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any collection/array of people or of people's birthdays.

Comment: `int days = 1/365;`: That is equivalent to `int days = 0`. int is the **integer** type, and 1/365 is an **integer** division.

Comment: the n is any given N that a user enters in parsing in the main

Comment: Check which value days has! It’s an integer and this can only hold whole numbers.

Comment: i changed the days to double - still doesn't work

Comment: Because 1 / 365 is an **integer** division. You're dividing two integers, and that leads to an integer. Use 1.0 / 365. Or 1 / 365.0. Or 1.0 / 365.0. All these would a double divisions.

Comment: You have also got the calculation of the probability wrong. The inverse probability (`1 - nprob`) has to be taken at the end, not in every loop iteration. And initialize `nprob` to 1, not 0.

Comment: what are you passing as input? input `6` I get `0.0099009901`

Comment: I mean, you should check the formula for the probability again. Your program currently does it wrong. I don't want to give away the complete solution since this is obviously some homework problem.

Comment: Thanks @Henry and JB  I changes the line to noProb =( noProb * (1- (person-1)*days)) and the days as you've told me and now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answered thanks to the comments:
changed days to

```
double days = 1.0 / 365.0;
```

and

```
 the noProb =(1-( noProb * (1- (person-1)*days)))/100;
```

to `noProb =( noProb * (1- (person-1)*days));`

and the return to `return (1-noProb);`
it now runs the same as the calculator in https://www.dcode.fr/birthday-problem